# javascript textbox text receiving posting and changing the color

Tags: javascript, html

```
<tr>
<td>page header</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" id="pageh" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Header color:</td>
<td>
    <select id="hcolor">
        <option>Red</option>
        <option>Purple</option>
        <option>Gray</option>
    </select></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>Header size</td>
<td>
    <select id="hsize">
        <option>12px</option>
        <option>18px</option>
        <option>24px</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Send" onclick="Start()" /><input type="reset" value="Clear" /></td>
</tr>
```

So, I want to take the textbox text, copy it into a var like this `var text = document.GetElementByID("pageh").value;` and then execute it to a `document.write` with the selected colors and sizes from the lists.

Comment: Excellent, what's the question exactly?

Comment: How can i do this?? Clicking the send button and then starting a function which will execute the text with the selected properties from the hcolor and the hsize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function Start() { 
    var text = document.getElementById('pageh').value; // get the value of the textbox
    var color_el = document.getElementById('hcolor');
    var color = color_el.options[color_el.selectedIndex].innerText.toLowerCase(); // get the selected color
    var size_el = document.getElementById('hsize');
    var size = size_el.options[size_el.selectedIndex].innerText; // get the font-size
    // make a p element with the selected style properties
    document.write("<p style='color: "+ color +"; font-size: " + size + "'>" + text + "</p>"); 
}
```

the `size_el.options` and `color_el.options` are element lists of the options in the select tags, 
The `size_el.selectedIndex` and `size_el.selectedIndex` are the selected options, represented by integers. so `color_el.options[2]` would give us the third option element. Then we "extract" the innerText from the elements.

Last we create an paragraph element, which looks something like `<p style="color: gray; font-size: 24px">test</p>` the color should preferable be written with lowecase letter, therefore we transform the "Gray" to "gray" by using "Gray".toLowerCase()

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very very much!
Can you add a little explanation please?